# Remove timestamp in the bracket from text Python

Tags: python, regex, timestamp, python-re, text-segmentation

I'd like to remove all the **timestamps** in the **parentheses** in the below sample text data.

**Input:**

> Agent: Can I help you? ( 3s ) Customer: Thank you( 40s ) Customer: I
> have a question about X. ( 8m 1s ) Agent: I can help here. Log in this
> website (remember to use your new password) ( 11m 31s )

**Expected Output:**

> Agent: Can I help you? Customer: Thank you Customer: I have a question
> about X. Agent: I can help here. Log in this website (remember to use
> your new password)

I tried `re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', data)` but it did not work as it removes everything in the parentheses. I want to keep the content in the parentheses if it is not a timestamp, for instance, I'd like to keep "(remember to use your new password)" in the output.

Still new to regex so hope I can get some guidance here. Thank you!

Comment: is it really one big block of text or it is on new line per participant? Also, it looks a bit suspicious that there is space between words and opening bracket, but not always

Comment: one row one chat log with a big block of text. so i'd apply the function across all rows.

Comment: The problem is not very well defined... Can't you get the data in some other way?

Comment: No I'm not able to get any other way. This is part of data cleaning after which I'll do analysis starting with word frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\(\s(\d{1,2}[smh]\s)+\)
```

FYI: `.*` matches everything except line terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Not regex and maybe not that efficient, but string methods will do:

```
spam = "Agent: Can I help you? ( 3s ) Customer: Thank you( 40s ) Customer: I have a question about X. ( 8m 1s ) Agent: I can help here. Log in this website (remember to use your new password) ( 11m 31s )"

def cleanup(text):
    for word in ('Agent', 'Customer'):
        text = text.replace(word, f'\n{word}').strip()
    clean_text = [line[:line.rindex('(')] for line in text.splitlines()]

    # or in slow-motion
    # clean_text = []
    # for line in text.splitlines():
    #     idx = line.rindex('(')
    #     line = line[:idx]
    #     clean_text.append(line)

    return ' '.join(clean_text)

print(cleanup(spam))
```

output

```
Agent: Can I help you?  Customer: Thank you Customer: I have a question about X.  Agent: I can help here. Log in this website (remember to use your new password)
```

EDIT: As suggested by [@DRPK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7343404/drpk) it can be optimized by making it one liner which will make difference in big corpus

```
clean_text = ' '.join([line[:line.rindex('(')] for line in text.replace("Agent", '\nAgent').replace("Customer", '\nCustomer').strip().splitlines()])
```

Comment: You can boost up your code just in one line: `clean_text = ' '.join([line[:line.rindex('(')] for line in text.replace("Agent", '\nAgent').replace("Customer", '\nCustomer').strip().splitlines()])`

Comment: I know it can be one-liner, but IMHO it's ugly and unreadble.

Comment: it dose not just make it one-liner, you said efficiency; one unnecessary extra for loop takes time (Reading/Replacing data two times? why? just imagine the huge corpus).

Comment: I agree it will be more efficient, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
\( [^\)]++\)
```

You can use this regex to replace with "" in your code.
I did generate it from http://www.amazingregex.xyz/. You can generate by yourself with text examples

Comment: I suggest you improve your asnswer,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)